# Why isn't it correct to claim that I have 4/24 possibilities?

Tags: probability

Which is more likely?

1. A: You roll a standard six-sided die four times and get the same
   number each time.
2. B: You roll a standard six-sided die four times and sum their
   outcomes to get 5.

The dice has 6 faces, so each time there's 1/6 for each side, I roll the dice 4 times, so I have 24 possibilities, why isn't it correct to claim that there's a 4/24 possibility?

Comment: There are more than $24$ outcomes. Think about this more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

For event $A: $
Out of the $6$ numbers on the die ,Let's pick one number to repeat $4$ times. This can be done in :$\binom{6}{1} $ ways. Our total number of cases are $6^4$ , making the probability:
$$\binom{6}{1} \cdot \left(\frac16\right)^4=\frac{1}{6^3}$$

For event $B: $
Let's call the outcomes needed to provide a sum of $5$ in $4$ tries be: $x_1 , x_2, x_3 ,x_4$. We are required to find the number of positive integral solutions of 
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=5 \ \ \text{ where } \ \ 1\leq x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\leq6$$ 
This can be done by [Fictitious Partition](https://www.slideshare.net/lohit91/permutation-and-combination-18285557). To find the number of solutions , we basically need the coefficient of $x^5$ in the expansion of : $\left(x+x^2+x^3+\cdots +x^6\right)^4$
$\therefore$ We need to find coefficient of $x^5$ in the expansion of:
$$x \left(\frac{x^6-1}{x-1}\right)^4$$
$$\Rightarrow \text{coefficient of $x^5$ in } x^4(1-x^6)^4(1-x)^{-4}$$
$$\Rightarrow \text{coefficient of $x$ in }(1-x^6)^4(1-x)^{-4} $$
$$ \Rightarrow \binom{4}{0}\cdot \binom{4}{1}=4$$
$\therefore$ Our probability of event $B$ is: $\frac{4}{6^4}=\frac{1}{6^3}\cdot \frac23$ 
Clearly event $B$ is less possible that event $A$

Answer (score 0):

If you roll the dice $4$ times, then you have $6\times6\times6\times6(=6^4)$ possibilities. So, the odds of getting the same number each of the for times is $\dfrac6{6^4}$, or $\dfrac1{6^3}$.

Comment: I don't get why

Comment: You roll the first dice. There are $6$ possibilities. You then roll the second dice. For *each* of the original possibilities, there are now other $6$ possibilities. So, now you have $6^2$ possibilities. And so on.

Comment: @Pier Try listing all of the possible outcomes of just two dice. You’ll find that there are a lot more than twelve.

Comment: Mh, I can see. Another question: why is the number of possibilities described by 6 to the power of whatever is the number of rolls?How can I think about it?

Comment: Because, by the same argument that I used to prove that, if you roll the dice twice, you have $6^2$ possibilites, if you roll it $k$ times, then you have$$\overbrace{6\times6\times\cdots\times6}^{k\text{ times}}$$possibilities.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos let me rephrase that, why is the number of possibilities described by 6 to the second, and in general by 6 to the power  whatever is the number of rolls?

Comment: It's $6^2$ because there are $6$ possibilities for the first dice and, for each of them, there are $6$ possibilities for the second one. So, you get a total of $6\times6$ possibilities.